# Check online status in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an website that allows user to add a movie to his google calendar by clicking 'Add to google caledar' button. My app needs to check first whether the user is online, before adding the moovie to his google calendar, and that's the thing I can't figure out.

javascript code, which I already tried:

```
if (navigator.onLine){ 
   var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
   'calendarId': 'primary',
   'resource': event
   });

   request.execute(function (event) {
      alert(`${element.title} was added to your google calendar!
      \nDate: ${convertToEuropeDate(dateInput.val())}
      \nTime: ${timeInput.val()}`);
      });
} else {
   alert('Can\'t add event to google calendar - you are offline');
}
```

The code above always says it's online and tells me that the event has been inserted, despite being disconnected from wifi.

I also tried this code - an ajax call to check online status by ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://google.com',
    success: function(data) {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'resource': event
        });
  
    request.execute(function (event) {
        alert(`${element.title} was added to your google calendar!
        \nDate: ${convertToEuropeDate(dateInput.val())}
        \nTime: ${timeInput.val()}`);
        });
}, error: function(data) {
   alert('Can\'t add event to google calendar - you are offline.');
   }
});
```

but the google page (and any other pages that I have already tried) always give me this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://google.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The last solution that I tried was to do API call, which I am using in my app, and check for errors. However, this also does not work - I don't know why, tho, this piece of code works in another part of my app.

```
fetch(url).then((resp) => {
    if (resp.ok) {
        return resp.json();
    } else {
        throw new Error();
        };
}).then(() => {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
    'calendarId': 'primary',
    'resource': event
    });
       
    request.execute(function (event) {
    alert(`${element.title} was added to your google calendar!
    \nDate: ${convertToEuropeDate(dateInput.val())}
    \nTime: ${timeInput.val()}`);
    });

}).catch((error) => {
    alert('Can\'t add event to google calendar - you are offline.');
});
```

Any ideas highly appreciated

Comment: Bear in mind that the device could well disconnect between you checking the online status and making the API call anyway, so you're back to square one really - are the google APIs just designed to work in an offline way anyway, so as far as you should be concerned, it _has_ been inserted correctly?

Comment: How do you mean "work offline?" When I click the button and no internet connection is present, the event will not be inserted into google calendar. If I am online, it is inserted.